# If $x = a +bi$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i],$ prove that $a^2+b^2>1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A problem from my algebra text:

> If $x = a +bi$ is not a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i],$ prove that $a^2+b^2>1.$

I think it's false since $x = 0 + 0i = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not a unit, but $0 + 0 \not> 1.$

Is this correct? Seems simple enough...

Edit: Also $x = -1 + \dfrac{1}{i}i = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with  $a^2 + b^2= (-1)^2 + \left(\dfrac{1}{i} \right)^2 = 1 + \dfrac{1}{i^2} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{-1} = 0 \not> 1$ works $(|x| = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = 0).$

Comment: I expect that when your algebra text says "$x=a+bi$", it implicitly means $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.  So your second example doesn't work in that case.  The first, however, does.  I guess it really means "non-zero and non-unit".

Comment: If $x$ is non-unit in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $x \ne \pm 1 \Longleftrightarrow |x| \ne 1 \Longleftrightarrow |x|^2 = a^2 + b^2 \ne 1.$ Since $x \ne 0,$ it follows that $|x| > 0$ but this implies $|x| > 1$ since $|x| \ne 1.$ Hence $|x|^2 > |x| > 1.$ Would this prove the statement for the case where we also assume that $x$ is non-zero?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as showing that if $a+bi\in \mathbb Z[i]$ is a unit then $a^2+b^2=1$

If $a+bi$ is a unit then $\exists c+di\in \mathbb Z[i]$ such that $(a+bi)(c+di)=1\implies (a-bi)(c-di)=1\implies (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$

$(a^2+b^2)=1$

If $(a^2+b^2)=1$ then $a=+1,-1,b=+1,-1$

Comment: From $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = 1$  you get that both  $(a^2+b^2)=1$ and $(c^2+d^2) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we are to assume $x = a + bi$ is a *non-zero*, *non-unit* element of $\Bbb Z[i]$.  We observe that for non-zero $a + bi \in \Bbb Z[i]$ we have $a^2 + b^2 > 0$; otherwise, $a = b = 0$.  So $a^2 + b^2$ must be a *positive* integer.  If $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, we may write

$(a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2 = 1, \tag{1}$

which shows that both $a \pm bi \in \Bbb Z[i]$ are units, i.e., divisors of $1$.  So for non-zero, non-unit $x = a + bi$ we must have $a^2 + b^2 > 1$.  ***QED.***